# Breezejs Web api OData method not allowed

Tags: asp.net, odata, breeze, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-odata

I am either getting a 400, 404, or 405 error attempting to query my Web API OData Service.

My remote service name is configured to:

```
var remoteServiceName = 'http://localhost:50056/odata/';
```

In my entityManagerFactory I have Odata set:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'webApiOData', true);
```

And in my datacontext I am calling:

```
var manager = entityManagerFactory.newManager();

    return breeze.EntityQuery.from('Courses')
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(success).catch(failed);
```

I am currently getting the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50056/odata/$metadata. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

I can access this path just fine in the browser. I've found several resources to suggest I need to set the httpProtocol in my web.config as follows:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

But that just gives me a

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50056/odata/$metadata. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
```

I have also tried to set these settings from IIS Express's applicationhost config file but that gives me the following:

```
Invalid HTTP status code 400
```

I have also heard that adding the following setting to WebApiConfig should work:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

But I see no effect, and alternatively I have tried:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Which also has no effect. I don't see what else I could be missing as I've exhausted every resource I've found online.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 express and using IIS express.

Comment: This looks like a CORS issue, not a Breeze issue. I know you say you've enabled it (and it looks like you did) but you need better evidence. One relatively quick approach is to write an HTML page with a script tag and inside that script tag is a jQuery AJAX call to the OData endpoints. Write to console if it returns successfully. Then open the Dev Tools (F12) and see what's going on.

Comment: Try `$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:50056/odata/$metadata"
})
  .then(function() {
    alert( "Got data" );
  }).catch(function(err) {alert("Failed: "+err.message)});`

Comment: Thanks for your response! That does work, but breeze gives me the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: @Ward It seems that jquery respects when I set config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "http://localhost:50063", "*", "*")); but angular/breeze does not in this case

Comment: I don't know if this means anything, but it looks like two "OPTIONS" requests are sent successfully to metadata, but two GET requests fail

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. I was using OData v4. Apparently datajs does not support OData v4 yet. Adding the following code in the WebApiConfig smoothed things out even further:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: I think you should tag it as answer :-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

Ahh. At the moment the Web Api implementation of OData is full of pot holes ... including but not limited to lagging data.js support.

I'm in touch with the OData team and hopeful we can make progress soon.

Do you really need OData? Unless you need to support open clients, it is much better to go straight Web Api.

Comment: Our issues have been with the Web Api OData implementation. You confuse me. Your question begins with a reference to Web Api OData. Now you're talking Java. As for client, our oob datasetvice relies on capabilities of datajs. FWIF, that is why your setting of CORS on jQuery had no effect; datajs does its own XHR. Usually unnecessary to enable CORS on browser ... unless you're working with an old browser. It would need to know more about your server and target browsers to be more helpful.